# How to pass Turkish username to SSRS report

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have a report in our system and the report has a  username parameter which is captured by using `user!userid`.
When our Turkish user logs in as ÇİĞDEM, the username passed into report as different characters.
Is there anyway to keep the Turkish username as what it is when the it's captured by the report?

Comment: try `Arial Unicode MS` font on the textbox where u r trying to display the trukish name..i used this for arabic and all and it works

Comment: The username will not be displayed, as it's an internal parametre only passed to the database. Is there a function that can be used to pass the Turtish username directly to the database? E.g function (user!userid)

Comment: didnt understand the requirement..u want to display or save it in database? while saving in database its showing as different charachter?

Comment: Sorry that I didnt make myself clear. The Turkish username is a report parametre. When the user login our system, the username will be passed to the report from the front-end login page. In the report, I used user!userid formula to capture the username and then pass it to the report query. However, the formula user!userid actually changed the Turtish username. As a result, the report query cant retrieve correct data.

Comment: whats the font in the textbox used to display the turkish char?